# rich:modalpanel will not show more than when invoked from form

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a problem with showing a `<rich:modalPanel>` more than once.
I have a form that has a `<a4j:commandlink onclick="#{rich:component('mp')}.show()"`
(have also tried a `rich:componentControl`).

This approach works fine once. Inside the modal panel I have a new form with some action attached to the submit button(`a4j:commandButton`). When this action completes the modalpanel is hidden using the same approach as above with `oncomplete="#{rich:component('mp')}.hide()"` , and the form containing the commandlink is reRendered.

Now, the problem is that the commandLink for showing the modalpanel does no longer work. If I put in an js `alert('something')` in the `onclick` event I can se that the `onclick` event is fired, but the modalpanel is not rendered.

Hope this is enough information...I can add some source code later if needed

Thanks

edit:
here's some more code:

```
<a4j:form prependId="false" ajaxSubmit="true">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="createActivityPanel">
        <h:panelGrid columns ="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.createActivityExpectedParticipantsLabel}" />
            <h:panelGrid columns ="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.createActivityAvailablePointsLabel}: #{sessionBean.loggedInUser.letspoints}" />
                <a4j:commandLink value="#{msg.createActivityGetMorePointsLinkLabel}" onclick="#{rich:component('convertPointsPanel')}.show()" />
                <rich:inputNumberSlider id="participantsSlider" value="#{activityRequestBean.newActivityExpectedNoParticipants}" maxValue="#{activityRequestBean.maxNoParticipants}" />
           </h:panelGrid>
       </h:panelGrid>
   </a4j:outputPanel>
</a4j:form>
<rich:modalPanel rendered="#{sessionBean.loggedIn}" id="convertPointsPanel" width="700" height="400">
    <a4j:support event="onhide" reRender="createActivityPanel"></a4j:support>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Velg poeng fra kategorier for å konvertere" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <a4j:form><a4j:commandButton id="closeButton" onclick="#{rich:component('convertPointsPanel')}.hide()" type="image" image="/img/close.gif"/></a4j:form>
    </f:facet>
    <a4j:form prependId="false" ajaxSubmit="true" id="convertPointsForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns ="2">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width:350px; float:left;">
                <rich:dataList var="catscore" value="#{pointsRequestBean.scores}" id="activityPointSliderList">
                    <h:graphicImage height="30" width="30" value="#{catscore.usercategoryscore.category.imagepath}" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{catscore.usercategoryscore.category.name}" />
                    <rich:inputNumberSlider maxValue="#{catscore.usercategoryscore.score}" value="#{catscore.transferredScore}" step="2" />
                </rich:dataList>
                <a4j:commandButton value="Konverter" id="convertButton" action="#{pointsRequestBean.convertPoints}" oncomplete="#{rich:component('convertPointsPanel')}.hide()" reRender="createActivityPanel"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width:350px; float:right; border-left: 1px solid #ACBECE; padding: 10px;">
                <h:outputText value="kjøp poeng fra paypal?" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </a4j:form>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

Notice that I've followed the advice in rerendering the panel instead of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you post the XHTML code?

Basically, one of your problem may be due to the fact that you reRender a form. Generally, it's not a good idea. One solution is to include a `<a4j:outputPanel>` and then re-render this panel instead of the form itself.

So instead of having:

```
<a4j:commandButton ... reRender="myForm"/>
<h:form id="myForm">
    ...
</h:form>
```

you can do:

```
<a4j:commandButton ... reRender="myFormContent"/>
<h:form id="myForm">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="myFormContent">
        ...
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

If this does not work, please add more code in your question.